# Approximating the Digamma function

Tags: numerical-methods, gamma-function, digamma-function

I am trying to approximate the digamma function in order to graph it in latex. I've already found an approximation of the gamma function from the Tex SE:
$$
\Gamma(z)=
    (2.506628274631\sqrt{(1/z)} + 0.20888568(1/z)^{(1.5)} + 0.00870357(1/z)^{(2.5)} - \frac{(174.2106599*(1/z)^{(3.5)})}{25920} - \frac{(715.6423511(1/z)^{(4.5)})}{1244160)}\exp((-ln(1/z)-1)z)
$$
and for the digamma, $\psi$, ive been using an approximation of the derivative:
$$
\psi(x)=\frac{\ln \Gamma(x+0.0001)-\ln \Gamma(x-0.0001)}{0.0002}
$$
But im wondering if there is a better way

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is a formula
$$ψ(x) \approx \log(x) - \frac{1}{2x} - \frac{1}{12x^2} +\frac{1}{120x^4} -\frac{1}{252x^6} +\frac{1}{240x^8} -\frac{5}{660x^{10}}+\frac{691}{32760x^{12}} -\frac{1}{12x^{14}}$$
This is especially accurate for larger values of $x$. If $x$ is small, you can shift $x$ to a higher value using the relation
$$ψ(x+1) = \frac{1}{x} + ψ(x)$$

You can find my source [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), under the "Computation and Approximation" section.

Edit: **Accuracy of Approximation**
This series is quite accurate for $x$ in the interval $(1,\infty)$. Given the OP's bounds of $x = (0,20)$, we can find the difference between the expected and calculated results (note that $S(x)$ is the series in question)
$$ψ(1) - S(1) = 0.0674022$$
$$ψ(20) - S(20) = 4.44089×10^{-16}$$
From these results we find that we get exactly what we expected: the series is decent in this interval, but is MUCH better for larger $x$. However, we get a problem for $x = \frac{1}{2}$:
$$ψ(\frac{1}{2}) - S(\frac{1}{2}) = 1285.81$$
Obviously we are way off here. However, some context is useful. Our series blows up for $x<1$ towards $-\infty$, and so we can't expect anything useful here. Nevertheless, we can use the shift formula above to mitigate this issue, rewriting it as
$$ψ(x) = ψ(x+1) - \frac{1}{x}$$
Applying this just once for $x=\frac{1}{2}$, we get a difference of $1.9816604...$, an approximation $\approx 650$ times better. Thus, we see that we can use the series provided to get a decent approximation of the graph of $ψ(x)$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: @dimebucker91 Sure thing! Note that this is an asymptotic series, hence why it works better for larger $x$ (and gets better and better as $x \to \infty$). I'm sure you can find series that are derived from other methods that will work for smaller values of $x$ with a little searching (if that is what you need)... it all depends on the domain you are graphing in

Comment: I was hoping to use it for $0<x \le 20$

Comment: @dimebucker91 Since it wasn't very general I didn't mention when you should apply the transform for small $x$ (especially since I haven't checked the bounds on when it provides a more correct answer and when it makes the solution worse), but I would guess the transform will work pretty well for all $x<1$. You might get a graph that appears excessively discontinuous, so some tinkering on when you apply the transform may be required.

Comment: Well, the function itself tends to $-\infty$ when $x \to 0+0$. I think it is possible to cut the plot at $x = 1$.

Answer (score 8):

Since you need an implementation for graphing, a simple approximation with relative low accuracy and optimized for absolute error seems suitable. A short search with computer program shows that $$\psi(x) \approx ln (x + a) - \frac{1}{b x}, \space a = 0.4849142940227510, \space b=1.0271785180163817$$
approximates with an absolute error of less than $0.00123$ on $[\frac{1}{2}, 2^{1024})$ when evaluated in IEEE-754 double precision. For arguments $x \lt \frac{1}{2}$, the function can be computed using the reflection formula $\psi(x) = \psi(1-x) + \pi \space cot \space(\pi (1-x))$.

Comment: How was this simple but well approximating formula derived?

Comment: @granularbastard It's a parameterized version of the simple approximation given at the top of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) on the Digamma function, $\ln x - \frac{1}{2x}$, which seems to have been taken from Abramowitz / Stegun per the references. In particular, this is 6.3.18 in A&S. The parameters were optimized by heuristic search.