# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\ln\big(\frac{1}{x}\big) \sin(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I'm having trouble with this integral

> Evaluate $$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \sin(x)dx$$

$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \sin(x)dx=\Im\left[\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x+ix}}{x}\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) dx\right]$$
How would one proceed from here ? $u$ substitute $u=\ln(x)$? How do you solve this integral? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you expected to use complex analysis to solve it? Have you solved or seen similar integrals before? You might want to search MSE with Approach0 for similar integrals : usually this allows you to at least get a better attempt in, for example.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I'm just learning it at the moment through problems

Comment: I see! I'd probably start with seeing that $\ln(\frac 1x) = -\ln x$. I've also got the exact expression for the answer over [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=integral+from+0+to+infinity+%5C%2840%29-Divide%5B%5C%2840%29Power%5Be%2C-x%5Dsin%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29ln+x%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5Ddx%5C%2841%29), so this is for others : it's equal to $\frac{\pi}{8}(2 \gamma + \log 2)$, so you might want to think about integrals involving $\gamma$.

Comment: Note that $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x(1-i)}}{x^a}\log x\, \mathrm dx=-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x(1-i)}}{x^a}$

Comment: @NoName Very close, it's just the $\frac 1x$ that's not been accounted for. The Frullani integral and contour approaches can possibly be modified to solve this one, though.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon In fact I didn't spot the slight difference. Thanks for pointing that out. I've now posted a solution to this question.

Comment: @NoName Noticed it, loved it, up voted it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We want to evaluate

$$I = -\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\ln (x)\sin(x)\, dx $$

We start with the result

$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\sin(x)\, dx = \frac{1}{a^2+1} = \frac{1}{2i}\Big(\frac{1}{a-i}-\frac{1}{a+i}\Big) $$

Differentiating both sides $ b-1$ times w.r.t. $a$ and setting $a=1$, we get

$$\int_0^\infty x^{b-1}e^{-x}\sin(x) \, dx = \frac{\Gamma(b)\sin\frac{\pi b}{4}}{2^{b/2}} $$

Now, differentiating w.r.t. $b$,
$$\int_0^\infty x^{b-1}\ln(x)e^{-x}\sin(x)\, dx = \frac{\Gamma(b)\psi(b)\sin\frac{\pi b}{4}}{2^{b/2}}+\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(b)\cos\frac{\pi b}{4}}{2^{b/2}}- \frac{\ln 2}{2}\cdot \frac{\Gamma(b)\sin\frac{\pi b}{4}}{2^{b/2}}$$
Now, taking the limit $b\to 0$, for which I used Wolfram|Alpha, we get the result
$$ I = \frac{\pi}{8}(2\gamma+\ln 2)$$
Where $\gamma$ denotes the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: It'd be nice if you could solve the limit as well, without requiring Wolfram Alpha. For example, it's well known that $b\Gamma(b) \to 1$ as $b \to 0$, and the first term involves the asymptotics of $\psi$, for which you can think about the series [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441753/approximating-the-digamma-function), shift the parameter up if necessary.

Comment: I would simply use $\int_0^\infty x^{b-1}e^{-ax}\,dx=a^{-b}\Gamma(b)$ for $\Re a, \Re b>0$, avoiding strange things like "differentiating $b-1$ times" (when $b$ is not an integer).

Comment: @metamorphy. There are also nice solutions using hypergeometric functions and even the expansion of $\sin(x)$ since $$\int_0^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1} e^{-x} x^{2 n} \log (x)}{(2 n+1)!}=\frac{(-1)^{n+1} \psi (2 n+1)}{2 n+1}$$

Comment: @metamorphy Actually, I avoid using complex numbers while I solve integrals, as I have not studied and am not much familiar to complex analysis. I am much familiar with the real methods I use.

Comment: @Teresa Well, I would try to figure it out. I think I have to use the asymptotic series representations of gamma and digamma functions. Any more hint you know?

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari The hints I gave will be enough, thankfully. I will anyway try a complex analytic approach, although metamorphy has given me food for thought!

Comment: @Teresa Yep. I feel really sad that I haven't learned complex analysis. I am trying to get the foundations required to learn it like multivariable calculus, algebra and real analysis. Only the last two are left.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari [This](http://www1.spms.ntu.edu.sg/~ydchong/teaching/08_contour_integration.pdf) is the best resource that I can suggest to you, apart from questions and answers on MSE of course. There aren't too many contour shapes or principles behind this , at least in simple cases. In fact, doing stuff while keeping your theorems real-analytic is plenty of fun on its own, so if you like you can continue avoiding complex integrations.

Comment: @Teresa If you can suggest me a good real and complex analysis book, it would be really helpful. I am almost done with my multivariable calculus, and want to learn real analysis after that.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari How about Rudin's Real and Complex analysis (and Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" as a precursor)? A solutions manual for it was created by Trang Tuan. For complex analysis alone, try Conway or Gamelin. For exercises in complex analysis, look at "A collection of problems in complex analysis" by Volkovyskii, Lunts and Aramanovich. These will help you get a move on very quickly!

Comment: @Teresa How about Apostol's real analysis? Would be better as an introduction?

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari Yes, that would work as well.

Comment: @Teresa for complex analysis, I was considering Schaum's complex variables and Frietag-Busam. Which would be better, in your opinion?

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari Haven't read either, sorry about that. The texts I have suggested are common undergraduate texts, so they will definitely have you on your way for sure.

Comment: @Teresa I will try them when I learn complex analysis. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

We'll use the following two crucial facts to calculate the integral. The first is that:

$$\boxed{\tan^{-1}x\ln(1+x^2)=-2\sum_{ n \ge 1}\frac{(-1)^nH_{2n}}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}}$$

which is shown in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240779/prove-ln1x2-arctan-x-2-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1n-h-2n2n1x2n1). The second is that

$$\displaystyle \boxed{\Gamma'(2k-1) = (2k-2)! \bigg(-2\gamma +2\sum_{n=1}^{2k-2}\frac{1}{n} \bigg)} $$

Which follows from logarithmic differentiation of $$\Gamma(2z-1)=e^{-\gamma (2z-2)}\cdot\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{2z-2}{n}\right)^{-1}e^{\frac{{2z-2}}n}$$

i.e. taking log of both sides and differenting w.r.t. $z.$

---

Let $\displaystyle I = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} \log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\sin x \, \mathrm dx. $ Using the taylor series for sine, we have:

$$\begin{aligned} I & = -\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} e^{-x} \log x \sin{x}\, \mathrm dx \\& = -\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} \log x \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1} x^{2k-2}}{(2k-1)!}\, \mathrm 
dx  \\& = -\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k-1)!}\int_0^{\infty}  x^{2k-2}e^{-x} \log x \, \mathrm 
dx \\& = -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k-1)!} \frac{\partial}{\partial k } \int_0^{\infty}  x^{2k-2}e^{-x} \, \mathrm 
dx \\&= -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k-1)!} \frac{\partial \Gamma (2k-1)}{\partial k } \\&= -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k-1)!} \cdot (2k-2)! \bigg(-2\gamma +2\sum_{n=1}^{2k-2}\frac{1}{n} \bigg) \\&= -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k-1)} \cdot \bigg(-2\gamma +2\sum_{n=1}^{2k-2}\frac{1}{n}\bigg) \\& = \gamma \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k-1)} -\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k-1)}\sum_{n=1}^{2k-2}\frac{1}{n} \\&= \frac{\gamma \pi }{4}- \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1} H_{2k-2}}{2k-1}  \\& = \gamma \frac{\pi}{4}- \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^k H_{2k}}{2k+1} \\& = \gamma \frac{\pi}{4}-\left( -\frac{1}{2} \cdot  \tan^{-1}x \cdot \ln(1+x^2)\right)\bigg|_{x=1} \\& = \gamma \frac{\pi}{4}+ \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\pi}{4} \cdot \log{2} \\& = \frac{\pi}{8} \left(2\gamma +  \log 2\right).  \end{aligned}$$

Comment: Atleast you didn't had to use a complicated limit, like I had to use. Nice answer.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari Thanks. Ah, yes that limit!

Answer (score 6):

Using the identities
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{x} &= \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x t}\, \mathrm{d} t, \\
 \ln x &= \int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-s} - \mathrm{e}^{-xs}}{s}\,\mathrm{d} s,
\end{align*}
we have
\begin{align*}
 I &= \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x}\sin x
 \left(\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x t}\, \mathrm{d} t\right)
 \left(\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-xs} - \mathrm{e}^{-s}}{s}\,\mathrm{d} s\right)\mathrm{d}x\\[8pt]
 &= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{s}
 \left[\int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x(1 + s + t)}\sin x \, \mathrm{d} x - \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x(1 + t) - s}\sin x\, \mathrm{d} x\right)\mathrm{d} t\right]\mathrm{d} s\\[8pt]
 &= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{s}
 \left[\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(1 + s + t)^2 + 1} - \mathrm{e}^{-s}\, \frac{1}{(1 + t)^2 + 1}\right)\mathrm{d} t\right]\mathrm{d} s  \tag{1}\\[8pt]
 &= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{s}
 \left[\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(1 + s) - \mathrm{e}^{-s}\,\frac{\pi}{4}\right]\mathrm{d} s\\[8pt]
 &= \lim_{c\to 0^{+}}
 \int_c^\infty \frac{1}{s}
 \left[\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(1 + s) - \mathrm{e}^{-s}\,\frac{\pi}{4}\right]\mathrm{d} s\\[8pt]
 &= \lim_{c\to 0^{+}}
 \left[ \Big(\frac{\pi}{4}\mathrm{e}^{-c} - \frac{\pi}{2} + \arctan(1 + c)\Big)\ln c  - \frac{\pi}{4}\int_c^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-s}\ln s \, \mathrm{d} s\right. \\[6pt]
&\qquad\qquad\left. + \int_c^\infty \frac{\ln s}{s^2 + 2s + 2}\,\mathrm{d} s\right]    \tag{2}\\[12pt]
 &= \frac{\pi}{4}\gamma + \frac{\pi}{8}\ln 2. \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Explanations:
(1): $\int \mathrm{e}^{-bx}\sin x \, \mathrm{d} x = -\frac{b\sin x + \cos x}{b^2 + 1}\mathrm{e}^{-bx}  + C$;
(2): the IBP (Integration By Parts);
(3): $\lim_{c\to 0^{+}} (\frac{\pi}{4}\mathrm{e}^{-c} - \frac{\pi}{2} + \arctan(1 + c))\ln c = 0$ (use L'Hopital rule),
and $\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-s}\ln s \, \mathrm{d} s = - \gamma$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant,
and $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln s}{s^2 + 2s + 2}\,\mathrm{d} s = \frac{\pi}{8}\ln 2$ (the proof is given at the end).

---

A very nice proof of $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln s}{s^2 + 2s + 2}\,\mathrm{d} s = \frac{\pi}{8}\ln 2$ by @Kelenner:

Let $J = \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln s}{s^2 + 2s + 2}\,\mathrm{d} s$.

With the substitution $s = \frac{2}{u}$, we have
$$J = \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln 2 - \ln u}{u^2 + 2u + 2}\,\mathrm{d} u
= \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln 2 }{u^2 + 2u + 2}\,\mathrm{d} u - J$$
which results in
$J = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln 2 }{u^2 + 2u + 2}\,\mathrm{d} u = \frac{\ln 2}{2}\arctan(1 + u)\vert_0^\infty = \frac{\pi}{8}\ln 2$. We are done.